# Sequence number of different nodes - XSLT

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xquery

I have an XML file with many nodes, and each different node has to have a sequence number.
How can I achieve this with XSLT 3.0?

**Input example:**

```
<root>
    <a>x</a>
    <a>x</a>
    <c>x</c>
    <d>x</d>
    <a>x</a>
    <c>x</c>
    <d>x</d>
    <b>x</b>
    <a>
        <x>.</x>
        <b>.</b>
    </a>
</root>
```

**Output example:**

```
<root serial='1'>
    <a serial='1'>x</a>
    <a serial='2'>x</a>
    <c serial='1'>x</c>
    <d serial='1'>x</d>
    <a serial='3'>x</a>
    <c serial='2'>x</c>
    <d serial='2'>x</d>
    <b serial='1'>x</b>
    <a serial='4'>
        <x serial='1'>.</x>
        <b serial='2'>.</b>
    </a>
</root>
```

Comment: How do you determine which serial number should be assigned to each node?

Comment: Which version of XSLT? In XSLT 3 you could set up an `xsl:acculator`, keeping map of counts by node name, in earlier versions (at least XSLT 2) some `xsl:number` should do the job.

Comment: I use XSLT 3.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [`xsl:number`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#number) to do this...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="serial">
                <xsl:number/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Working example: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVTWaA4/2

Comment: Thanks, that's almost working, but the number needs to be added for all elements, including child nodes.

Comment: @gh0st1822 - You can change the match from `/*/*` to just `*` for all elements, but that would include `root`. If you want to exclude the root element, you could use `*[parent::*]`. (Updated answer based on question changes.)

Comment: Also, you should update your question with an example of children and what the numbering should look like. You will probably need to use a `level` attribute if children have the same name as parents/ancestors and if the numbering needs to continue.

Comment: @gh0st1822 - My answer has been updated too. Let me know if you're still having trouble.